# Why does this flatMap fail?

Tags: scala

```
scala> val s: Seq[Class[_ <: java.lang.Enum[_]]] = Seq(classOf[java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit])
s: Seq[Class[_ <: java.lang.Enum[_]]] = List(class java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

scala> s.flatMap(_.getEnumConstants)
<console>:9: error: no type parameters for method flatMap: (f: Class[_ <: java.lang.Enum[_]] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Seq[Class[_ <: java.lang.Enum[_]]],B,That])That exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Class[_ <: java.lang.Enum[_]] => scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps[_$1(in value $anonfun) with java.lang.Object] forSome { type _$1(in value $anonfun) <: java.lang.Enum[_] })
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : Class[_ <: java.lang.Enum[_]] => scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps[_$1(in value $anonfun) with java.lang.Object] forSome { type _$1(in value $anonfun) <: java.lang.Enum[_] }
 required: Class[_ <: java.lang.Enum[_]] => scala.collection.GenTr...              s.flatMap(_.getEnumConstants)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really the precise answer, but two observations - Scala 2.10 will give you a nicer error:

```
scala> s.flatMap(_.getEnumConstants)
<console>:9: error: no type parameters for method flatMap: (f: Class[_ <: Enum[_]] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Seq[Class[_ <: Enum[_]]],B,That])That exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Class[_ <: Enum[_]] => scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps[(some other)_$1(in object $iw) with Object] forSome { type (some other)_$1(in object $iw) <: Enum[_] })
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : Class[_ <: Enum[_]] => scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps[(some other)_$1(in object $iw) with Object] forSome { type (some other)_$1(in object $iw) <: Enum[_] }
 required: Class[_ <: Enum[_]] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?B]
              s.flatMap(_.getEnumConstants)
                ^
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Class[_ <: Enum[_]] => scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps[(some other)_$1(in object $iw) with Object] forSome { type (some other)_$1(in object $iw) <: Enum[_] }
 required: Class[_ <: Enum[_]] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B]
              s.flatMap(_.getEnumConstants)
                          ^
<console>:9: error: Cannot construct a collection of type That with elements of type B based on a collection of type Seq[Class[_ <: Enum[_]]].
              s.flatMap(_.getEnumConstants)
                   ^
```

And, if you split your `flatMap`, you get to see a simpler version of the issue:

```
scala> s.map(_.getEnumConstants)
res28: Seq[Array[_$1 with Object] forSome { type _$1 <: Enum[_] }] = List(Array(NANOSECONDS, MICROSECONDS, MILLISECONDS, SECONDS, MINUTES, HOURS, DAYS), Array(RELEASE_0, RELEASE_1, RELEASE_2, RELEASE_3, RELEASE_4, RELEASE_5, RELEASE_6))
scala> res28.flatten
<console>:10: error: No implicit view available from Array[_$1 with Object] forSome { type _$1 <: Enum[_] } => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B].
              res28.flatten
                    ^
```

That is rather surprising since you'd think that it should be easy to turn an `Array` into a `GenTraversableOnce`. I don't have time to dig out the details at the moment, but I'll point out that the following things seem to work:

```
s.flatMap(_.getEnumConstants.toSeq)
s.flatMap(_.getEnumConstants.map(_.asInstanceOf[Enum[_]]))
```

I vote compiler bug, because of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/themel/5141394), which shows some very weird behaviour in the REPL for this simple script

```
val s: Seq[Class[_ <: java.lang.Enum[_]]] = Seq(classOf[java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit], classOf[javax.lang.model.SourceVersion])
s.flatMap(_.getEnumConstants.toSeq)
s.flatMap(_.getEnumConstants.toArray)
1234
```

Comment: As pointed out in my other comment, I would expect that `Predef.genericArrayOps` provides the needed conversion from the `Array[TimeUnit]` to `ArrayOps[TimeUnit]`, which inherits from `GenTraversableOnce[TimeUnit]` as expected from the `flatMap` call.

Comment: I agree, the question boils down to why it does not seem to trigger the implicit (and maybe whether it should).

Comment: My guess right now is that the issue's related to the needed implicit `CanBuildFrom[Seq[Class[_ <: java.lang.Enum[_]]], TimeUnit, Seq[TimeUnit]]`, but at the moment I can't find which source file contains the default implicit typeclass builders. I suppose that posting to the scala-users group would solicit some more informed answer.

Answer (score 2):

`TimeUnit.getEnumConstants` returns a java array `TimeUnit[]`, while `flatMap` expects a `GenTraversable`

You can get by with

```
scala> s.flatMap(_.getEnumConstants.toSeq)
res4: Seq[Enum[_]] = List(NANOSECONDS, MICROSECONDS, MILLISECONDS, SECONDS, MINUTES, HOURS, DAYS)
```

Comment: I'm confused, my simple understanding is that Java TimeUnit[] is the same type as Array[TimeUnit] in Scala, so there shouldn't be a difference, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Actually I'm starting to have some doubt myself if this shouldn't work as you expect. I should check-out some low-level spec or manual.

Comment: What I see is that `Array[T]` doesn't directly inherits the `Traversable`-some trait, but it must be implicitly converted from `Predef.genericArrayOps` or `Predef.genericWrapArray` to get the *traversable-like* operations. It can be that the implicit conversion is not available in the context of the lambda passed as parameter to `flatMap`, though I don't see why.